# how to efficiently bin data in matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram, binning

I want to bin some data according to some 'steps', here `1:10`. So `bin{1}` should contain values `>=steps(1) & <steps(2)` etc.

I'm wondering if I can get some tips/feedback from the community, put into a question: is there some common practice for binning data that I haven't found yet, can the code be improved in terms of efficiency and readability?

```matlab
data=abs(sin(0:.1:10)*10); %example data
steps=1:10; %user-defined bins
betw=@(x,mi,ma) x(x>=mi & x<ma); %function that returns values between minimum/maximum

bin={};
for ind=1:numel(steps)-1
  bin{ind}=betw(data,steps(ind),steps(ind+1));
end
bin

bin =

  1×9 cell array

  Columns 1 through 7

    {1×7 double}    {1×7 double}    {1×7 double}    {1×8 double}    {1×9 double}    {1×7 double}    {1×10 double}

  Columns 8 through 9

    {1×11 double}    {1×27 double}
```

Comment: Depends what your want to do after with the data, I guess.

Comment: bar/errorbar plot it bin-wise =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`histcounts`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html) function would be the "standard" way to do this:

```
data = abs(sin(0:.1:10)*10); %example data
steps = 1:10;                %user-defined bins

hc = histcounts( data, steps );
>> hc = 
  [ 7 7 7 8 9 7 10 11 27 ]
```

Note that `hc` is one element smaller than `steps` because `steps` defines the bin edges. The total counts `sum(hc)` is equal to the number of elements in `data` which fell between the lowest and highest bins - in this case fewer than `numel(data)` because some elements of `data` are lower-valued than your lowest bin in `steps`.

There are many options within `histcounts` to return the bin edges, specify number of bins rather than edges, return the bin number for each element, etc...

If all you actually want is the bar plot (noted in your comment), you can use `histogram`, which calls `histcounts` under-the-hood for the computation, but outputs a figure too.

```
histogram( data, steps );
```

[image: histogram]

Comment: I wasn't aware of that @histogram 2nd parameter, thank you